# how to find the largets numbers in each line in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

Write a program that opens  the following  file (numbers1.txt ) that contains 4 lines of numbers as follows:

```
numbers1.txt
 100   900
-3.2   25.9 
30       11
 ( Empty line)
200    500
```

The program should read the two numbers in every line and print the maximum using max() function
The program should Print a message when there isn't a number

my code doesn't work??

```
f=open('numbers1.txt','r')
list1=f.readlines()
for i in list1:
    print(max(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the error?

try this:

`for i in list1:
    print(max(i.strip())`

No empty lines.

Answer (score 0):

Param of max() should be a sequence. Use split() to change string to sequence.

```
for i in list1:
    if len(i) != 1:  # not empty line
        print(max(i.split()))
```

Don't forget close a file, or use: with open('numbers1.txt') as f, which closes a file on itself.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has some issues:

1. The `max()` function is called with a single string argument (the string `'100   900'` for example) but is expecting **two** values. Use `line.split()` for that purpose.
2. I guess string values should be converted to `float` before evaluating `max()`.
3. You should handle empty lines.
4. You should close the file  after reading.

This code should fix the issues:

```
with open('numbers.txt', 'r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if line.strip() == '':
            continue
        n1, n2 = line.split()
        max_value = max(float(n1), float(n2))
        print(max_value)
```

The snippet can be abbreviated, but I've just added extra lines for pedagogic purposes only.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution could be:

```
n = len(list1)
for i in range(0,n):
    x = (list1[i].split())
    if not x: # skip if line is empty
        continue
    print(max(x))
```